# How to remove a a randomly selected value from a specific sublist using a variable to define the random value that needs to be removed?

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to make a function that takes a random variable from a sublist and removes it after it is selected. But for some reason, when I use a variable to define what to be removed, it removes from multiple sublists, while actually not removing anything from those sublists at all? I can't describe this very well because I don't understand it well myself. Here's some code that I wrote to try and duplicate the problem:

```
greet = [[1,"Hello!"],[2,"Hi!"], [3,"Howdy!"]]
person = [["John", greet], ["Sally", greet], ["Frank", greet]]

while True:

    #This is meant to catch the error random gives when there is an empty list, so it continues if there's an empty list.
    #When all lists in person[0][1] and [1][1] and so on and so forth are empty, there is a break function below.

    try:  
        person_select = random.choice(person)
        greet_select = random.choice(person_select[1])
        person_and_greet_order = [person_select[0], greet_select[1], greet_select[0]]
        print(person_and_greet_order)

        #This should be activating, but it isn't, leading to an infinite loop
        if person[0][1]==[] and person[1][1]==[] and person[2][1]==[]:
            print("Everyone greeted!")
            break

        #Tests to see if greeting was used on person, then remove that greeting from the list so it can't be used again.
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="John":
            person[0][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="Sally":
            person[1][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="Frank":
            person[2][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)

            #The else is here to see if it's properly detecting the names. 
        else:
            break
    except:
        continue
```

Here's what you'll get from it:

```
[['John', [[2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Sally', [[2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Frank', [[2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]]]
['John', 'Hi!', 2]
[['John', [[3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Sally', [[3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Frank', [[3, 'Howdy!']]]]
['Frank', 'Howdy!', 3]
[['John', []], ['Sally', []], ['Frank', []]]
```

(And after this it loops to infinity because the if statement doesn't see that the lists are empty, even though they are?)

As you can see, it removes the value from EVERY sublist instead of the specific sublist, when I need it to just remove a value from one. And the empty lists are not registering as empty lists even though they are empty. The end goal is to get every possible combination of greetings and people. I'm really new to python and I don't know anything I can do here. I'm at the end of my rope. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have only one sublist with three references to it from `person`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same reference to `greet` in `person`, which is wrong, and what should be done is that you should use a copy of `greet` in the `person` list instead using `greet[:]`

To expand, an assignment like `b = a` doesn't create a real copy of a list as one would expect it to, but instead what ends up happening is both variables just point to the same list in memory. 
So changing something in `a` will reflect in `b` as well

To actually create a copy, we need to do `b = a[:]` like we do for `greet[:]`

Hence the updated code will look like so

```
import random
greet = [[1,"Hello!"],[2,"Hi!"], [3,"Howdy!"]]

#Use a copy of greet via list slicing
person = [["John", greet[:]], ["Sally", greet[:]], ["Frank", greet[:]]]

while True:

    #This is meant to catch the error random gives when there is an empty list, so it continues if there's an empty list.
    #When all lists in person[0][1] and [1][1] and so on and so forth are empty, there is a break function below.

    try:  
        person_select = random.choice(person)
        greet_select = random.choice(person_select[1])
        person_and_greet_order = [person_select[0], greet_select[1], greet_select[0]]
        print(person_and_greet_order)

        #This should be activating, but it isn't, leading to an infinite loop
        if person[0][1]==[] and person[1][1]==[] and person[2][1]==[]:
            print("Everyone greeted!")
            break

        #Tests to see if greeting was used on person, then remove that greeting from the list so it can't be used again.
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="John":
            person[0][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="Sally":
            person[1][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)
        elif person_and_greet_order[0]=="Frank":
            person[2][1].remove(greet_select)
            print(person)

            #The else is here to see if it's properly detecting the names. 
        else:
            break
    except:
        continue
```

And the output will be

```
['Frank', 'Howdy!', 3]
[['John', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Sally', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['John', 'Hello!', 1]
[['John', [[2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Sally', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['Sally', 'Howdy!', 3]
[['John', [[2, 'Hi!'], [3, 'Howdy!']]], ['Sally', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['John', 'Howdy!', 3]
[['John', [[2, 'Hi!']]], ['Sally', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['John', 'Hi!', 2]
[['John', []], ['Sally', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['Sally', 'Hello!', 1]
[['John', []], ['Sally', [[2, 'Hi!']]], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['Sally', 'Hi!', 2]
[['John', []], ['Sally', []], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!'], [2, 'Hi!']]]]
['Frank', 'Hi!', 2]
[['John', []], ['Sally', []], ['Frank', [[1, 'Hello!']]]]
['Frank', 'Hello!', 1]
[['John', []], ['Sally', []], ['Frank', []]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because lists are (by default) copied by reference in python. When you add `greet` to your person arrays, try replacing `greet` with `deepcopy(greet)`. This makes a separate copy of that list in memory, so changing it won't affect your other lists.

This requires the additional import `from copy import deepcopy`